# how i know the accuracy of the Kmeans?

Tags: python, k-means, hierarchical-clustering

```
from datetime import time
from numpy import random
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
from  sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


     df = pd.read_csv( "spam.csv"  )

feature_col=['total']
X=df[feature_col]
y=df.target
  clf_km=KMeans(n_clusters=1)
clf_km=clf_km.fit(X)


clf_km.cluster_centers_
clf_km.labels_
```

I try to implement the Kmeans clustering but I don't know how I can plot the original clusters and the new ones I created by the kmeans, I want to plot to scatter for the original one and another for the new[part of the csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUKK3.png) .

Comment: Is your question - `how do i plot my clusters?` Did you search with something like `python kmeans plot site:stackoverflow.com` - Lots of examples in the Q&A's - each cluster gets a different color, plot some kind of symbol at the cluster centroids, make two plots one for the new and one for the original.  Your question is either too broad or a duplicate. If you find a Q&A that answers yor question, let us know and we will mark yours as a duplicate.

Comment: Browse through the [Matplotlib Gallery](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/index.html) - you can probably adapt from something in there. Like [https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/scatter_with_legend.html](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/scatter_with_legend.html)